# Iframe Auto resize not working in Firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, autoresize

I am using this script to resize iframe height and width automatically based on the content..

```
<script language="JavaScript">


function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
</script>
```

Calling this function in Iframe onload..

```
<iframe src="index.htm" scrolling='no'  width="100%" height="100%" name="CHANGETHIS" id="CHANGETHIS" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');"></iframe>
```

Consider I am using hyperlink `<a href="index2.htm">Redirect</a>`

If I click `Redirect` hyperlink, it is redirecting to `index2.htm` file with iframe auto resize based on the content. If I go back (browser back or back button) to the previous page (index.htm), iframe auto resize is not working only in firefox..It is working fine in IE..

Is there any solution for this to work also in firefox using javascript or jquery?

Comment: $(window).on('resize',function(){...}); !!!

Comment: Welcome C-link..you have answered many of my questions..Can you please explain this jquery? How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: `onresize="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');"`

```
<iframe src="index.htm" scrolling='no'  width="100%" height="100%" name="CHANGETHIS" id="CHANGETHIS" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onload="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');" onresize="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');"></iframe>
```

Comment: what about autoresize function that I mentioned in javascript?  Can I delete that ?

Comment: nope, that's your function and if you use onresize inline js then copy my answer that is <iframe....> and if you would like to use in js file then within on resize function place your code.

Comment: Couldn't get you bro...:(

Comment: I fixed it bro..Problem in height of iframe..I have set it to 0px once the html loaded..now it is working fine..Thanks for your help..